Android Studio UI Broken when opening Android Emulator
I have a problem with the android studio UI display when opening the android emulator on the macOs Big Sur operating system, some backgrounds / colors become broken such as on the background of notifications, selected items, buttons (ok, apply, cancel and others). I have tried using Genymotion but the results are the same. This problem does not occur when I use windows OS on the same device.
My device MacBook Pro late 2013
when opening an emulator:

when not opening the emulator:


This is not right place to ask this you can report it by following the instructions here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533

no answer yet > https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/361885732

The problem was solved after I added -Dsun.java2d.metal=false in VM option.
